# Java call static method of enum that is passed as class type variable without casting

Tags: java, enums, interface, casting

I have two enums:

```
public enum Animal {
    DOG, CAT
    public static void die() {
        // ...
    }
}

public enum Plant {
    APPLE, GRASS
    public static void die() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I have a the following logic

```
private void startHere() {
    callMe(Animal.class);
    callMe(Plant.class);
}

private void callMe(Class<?> _class) {
    if (_class == Plant.class) {
        Plant.class.cast(_class).die(); // OK
    }

    if (_class == Animal.class) {
        Animal.class.cast(_class).die(); // ok
    }
}
```

How can I process the `_class` parameter and call the corresponding `die()` static method on it, dynamically, without the if comparison and casting?

Normally I would use interfaces. The problem is that overriding a static method defined in interface not possible in Java.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Despite having the same name, `Animal.die()` and `Plant.die()` are unrelated functions. There's no generic way to invoke them.

The name "die" suggests they should be instance, not static, methods. An animal instance can die, yes? Not the animal class? If you make them instance methods then you could have both enums implement a common interface:

```
interface Mortal {
    void die();
}

enum Animal implements Mortal { ... }
enum Plant  implements Mortal { ... }
```

Or if you really do intend for them to be static, you could replace the `if` statements with map-based lookup. It's still not a compile-time construct, but avoids casting.

```
Map<Class<?>, Runnable> killers = new HashMap<>();
killers.add(Plant .class, Plant ::die);
killers.add(Animal.class, Animal::die);

...

killers.get(_class).run();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Normally I would use interfaces. The problem is that overriding a static method defined in interface not possible in Java.

Yes, but you can wrap the call in an interface. Using method references this is pretty simple:

```
private void startHere() {
    callMe(Animal::die);
    callMe(Plant::die);
}

private void callMe(Runnable m) {
    m.run();
}
```